# How to change button text belonging to a particular row in JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, getattribute

I am working on **html/php code** as shown below in which on click of button, I want to change the **Go** button text to **Converting**.

```
<?php  foreach ($programs as $key => $program) {  ?> 
   <tr data-index="<?php echo $key; ?>">
      <td><input style="text-align:center; width:90px;"  onclick="change()" type="submit"  id="go-btn" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" ></input></td>
   </tr>
<?php }?>
```

At this moment, I have 2 rows at UI. Below is the code on inspect:

```
<tr data-index="0">
   <td><input onclick="change()" type="submit" id="go-btn" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="0" class="go-btn btn btn-outline-primary">
   </td>
</tr>

<tr data-index="1">
   <td><input onclick="change()" type="submit" id="go-btn" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="1" class="go-btn btn btn-outline-primary">
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is what I have tried but more need to be done.

```
 function change() 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("go-btn");
    var attribute = elem.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(attribute);  // It will print 0 everytime as it is taking the data-id value in the document. 
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **JS code** above so that on click of button, the text inside the button 
belonging to particular row should change from **Go** to **Converting**.

Comment: You should never have more than one element in the same page with the same id. Id is supposed to have a unique value over the page. Otherwise many things may not work as expected. For instance, getElementById will always return only one element, no matter how many elements with the same id are there in the page

Comment: @Santi Thats on inspect. Probably I can remove the id from the html/php code. I am using foreach loop with the table which is generating multiple rows on inspect.

Comment: If you don't use that id nothing bad will happen, but if you mean to use it you are supposed to desing the page so that every id has a unique value. Because many tecnologies (css, javascript, etc) assume that every id belongs to only one element and work according to that assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click event listener to inputs with the name `go-button`. If you change the .`val` then this changes the text displayed to the user. I have also disabled the buttons after they are clicked, as I imagine this is the expected behaviour in your case (i.e. the user has to wait for the conversion to be completed).

Once completed you can re-enable the button if necessary with `.attr("disabled", "false")`

N.B. `id` should be unique, so you should try and change the id for your buttons if possible.

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to the inputs with class .go-button
$("input[name='go-button']").click( function() {

  // Change the text of the button, and disable
  $(this).val("Converting").attr("disabled", "true");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr data-index="0">
   <td><input type="submit" id="go-btn" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="0" class="go-btn btn btn-outline-primary">
   </td>
</tr>

<tr data-index="1">
   <td><input type="submit" id="go-btn" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="1" class="go-btn btn btn-outline-primary">
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Its working perfectly fine. I have one small issue. Text `Converting` comes for a flash of second and then it goes to `Go`

Comment: Very odd, sounds like something else is setting the `value` of the input? I'd check the rest of your JS

Comment: My fault, you edited the code. I saw the edited code later. My apologies. Also, I am wondering how I can change the width of the button when `Converting` text shows up ? The converting text doesn't seems to fit properly in the button.

Comment: I have edited the question to show what was there before.

Comment: Lets say, when Converting text shows up, I want width to be `120px`

Comment: I did this  `$(this).val("Converting").attr("disabled", "true").css({'width': '120px'});` and it worked.

Comment: Yep perfect. Glad it’s all working now! Good luck with ffs project

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572410/how-to-know-system-command-is-in-use-in-php). Its not similar but having the same code. I am wondering if you can have a look.