# How to know system command is in use in php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload, progress-bar

I have a **HTML/PHP code** as shown below in which **on click of a button** conversion of mp4 into mp3 starts happening.

**HTML/PHP Code:**

```
   <?php  foreach ($programs as $key => $program) {  ?> 
       <tr data-index="<?php echo $key; ?>">
          <td><input type="submit"  id="go-btn" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" ></input></td>
       </tr>
    <?php }?>
```

**Php code (where mp4=>mp3 conversion happens):**

```
$f = $mp4_files[$_POST['id']];
$parts = pathinfo($f);  
switch ($parts['extension'])
{  
case 'mp4' :
$filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
system('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result); 
break;  
}
```

As soon as the button is clicked from the **HTML/PHP** Code above, the text gets changed from **Go** to **Converting** in the UI because I have added JS/jQuery code in my codebase but this **JS/jQuery code** which I have added just change the text only.

It doesn't actually know that the Conversion is happening in the background.

**JS/jQuery code:**

```
$("input[name='go-button']").click( function() {

  // Change the text of the button, and disable
  $(this).val("Converting").attr("disabled", "true");

});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering **what modification** I need to do in the  **JS/jQuery** code above so that UI actually knows that conversion is happening in the background.

Probably, we need to add make establish some connection between **JS/jQuery** and **php** code above but I am not sure how we can do that.

Comment: If the button is still active then you need to change it to $(this).val("Converting").attr("disabled", "disabled"); and when the conversion has been completed re-enable the button by $(this).val("Converting").attr("disabled", "");

Comment: I am not sure when you say "button is still active"

Comment: Can you still click on the button when it is showing the text Converting as this would start another conversion process.

Comment: no, I can't click on the text **Converting** when the conversion is happening based on the code which i have pasted.

Comment: Sorry I might have misread your question. So I gather that you want a progress bar on what is happening? If so the google 'php file upload progress bar' there are tons of stuff out there. The info deals with the file upload so once you figure that out then you need to be able to get info from ffmpeg processing and display that.

Comment: Yes, once the conversion is happening using ffmpeg I want the button text to be changed from `Go` to `Converting` and when its finished, it should be `Completed`

Comment: Commenting as @flash asked me to check out the question. Unfortunately I'm out of my depth with PHP, but jeff is right - you need to re-enable the button once the conversion is complete. Can you launch a bit of javascript on completion of the PHP conversion?

Comment: @OliverTrampleasure Yes, I need to re-enable the button once the conversion is complete. Also, **JS/jQuery** code which I have added with the help of you just change the text only. It doesn't know whats happening in the background.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to know what is happening in the background... You could just trigger a JS function once the conversion is completed that re-enabled the button with `.attr("disabled", "")` or `.removeAttr("disabled")`. I don't know how you would trigger a JS function when the process is completed though... I don't have much experience with PHP

Comment: I assume that you are using AJAX to upload the file (your submitted code does not show this). Within the AJAX call you can use .done(function( msg ) {///change button text (see jQuery AJAX docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: When you say upload the file, I am not sure what you mean. In the php code where `mp4=>mp3` conversion happens, it looks for a mp4 file in the  `src_directory` and placed it into `destination_directory` after the conversion is complete.

Comment: Yes I am using AJAX to call the `Php code (where mp4=>mp3 conversion happens):`. I didn't mention in the question as the question would look too big.

Comment: @jeff This is my ajax code https://jsfiddle.net/xw68d91h/